# Coldfusion Video tutorials

Tags: coldfusion

I am pretty much interested in learning coldfusion technology.However the text based guide though wonderful seems to be monotonous at times and i frequently lose focus.Even though i have developed my skill in coldfusion with the textual guide i would suggest to come up with video tutorials that will grab prgramers interest.Adobe is on way to bring cf 10 and 11.How about with video tutorials??

Or else if there is any video tutorials available plz provide a link for the same.

Consider this as my suggestion.

Thanks,Tauq

Answer (score 2):

Here they are, AFAIK only CF related video training available:

From Lynda : http://www.lynda.com/ColdFusion-training-tutorials/174-0.html

From VTC : http://www.vtc.com/products/Adobe-ColdFusion-8-Advanced-Tutorials.htm

After you get grip over basics, knock yourself out with HUGE library of how-tos and meetings over at http://www.meetup.com/coldfusionmeetup/messages/boards/

Answer (score 1):

http://tv.adobe.com/product/coldfusion/

http://www.lynda.com/ColdFusion-training-tutorials/174-0.html

http://www.carehart.org/ugtv/

Good luck. :)